# Collect/transfer data from form/one google sheet to log/second google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// collect data.
const sourcerange = ss.getRangeByName("b94:h94");
const sourceVals = sourcerange.getValues();


// skip val, gather user email
const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

const data = {email,sourceVals};

console.log(data);

//append data
const destinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("test log");
destinationsheet.appendRow(data);
```

---

**edit:  error happening here**

```
const destinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("test log");
destinationsheet.appendRow(data);
```

**here is the error message**

> Exception: The parameters ((class)) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow.
> myFunctionx @ Code.gs:19

Comment: Please [edit] your code to include a [mre] as a code block and read [ask]

Comment: Hi @Ana H. Do you need the email address of the user running the script to be part of the data you transfer to the log shet?? Also, As Rojo mentioned, please provide the code block and readh the how to Ask section

Comment: @MatiasCG - email isn't really needed, but helpful for tracking of who is using.  

Sorry, new here.. just answered/filled the questions ... what do you mean by code block?

Comment: Please post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: updated to show code.. I think?

Comment: FIRST please [google the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+parameters++don%27t+match+the+method+signature+for+spreadsheetapp.sheet+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: yes, I goggled the error and it wasn't helpful, so now I'm here.. thought it would be more helpful but... thanks?

Comment: The [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) says append an array

Comment: If sourceVals is an array, try `const data = [email, ...sourceVals]`

Comment: just tried, gave me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the email address of the person that ran the script to be the first value of the row that will be pasted into test log. Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 // collect data.
 const sourcerange = ss.getRangeByName("b94:h94");
 const sourceVals = sourcerange.getValues();


 // skip val, gather user email
 const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 const newVals = [email, ...sourceVals[0]].flat();
 console.log(newVals);

 //append data
 const destinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("test log");
 destinationsheet.appendRow(newVals);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having an issue with all the collected data showing up on the actual log.  Is there another way to code that?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on that question? I do not understand what exactly you  need next.  If you think your next question will take some large text to explain. You could maybe create another post. Since I assume your problem regarding the current question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sourcerange = sh1.getRange("b2:h2");
  const sourceVals = sourcerange.getValues().flat();;
  const destinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sourceVals.unshift(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
  destinationsheet.appendRow(sourceVals);
}
```